# Composer Install Magento 2 as a Dev Dependency

Tags: php, magento, composer-php, magento2

I'm trying to develop a theme for Magento 2 by creating a composer module and loading Magento 2 as a dev dependancy by installing it into a subfolder and linking my theme in from a separate `src/` subdirectory.

I'm currently trying the following in my `composer.json` file which results in the module being installed to the root directory:

```
"require-dev": {
    "composer/installers": "*",
    "magento/project-community-edition": "2.0.*"
},
"extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
        "magento/": ["type:product"]
    }
}
```

From working on Magento 1 I was able to have the following directory structure to develop and test my module:

```
magento/
src/
composer.json
modman
```

With composer.json set as follows:

```
"require-dev": {
    "composer/installers": "~1.0",
    "magento/ce": "1.9.2.*"
},
"extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
        "magento": ["type:magento-source"]
    }
}
```

Is this possible to do with Magento 2? Or would I be better running 2 different projects specifying my theme as a dependency and how would I link these together to develop on if so?

Comment: If magento/ is your Magento root, I'm pretty sure that it's not possible to have a src/ directory at the same level. it's easiest to use magento/vendor instead. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of composer's [repository with artifact](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#artifact) as

```
"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "artifact",
            "url": "path/to/directory/with/zips/"
         }
     ],
```

where `path/to/directory/with/zips/` should contain the zipped package of your theme.

Also, you do not need dependencies on `"composer/installers"` or `magento/project-community-edition` only required will be `"magento/framework"`